# How to convert any decimal numbers to its next integer in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I know that there are two function 'fix' and 'round' which can convert decimal to integer. However, I cant find a way to round off any decimal number to its next integer. Anyone know how this can be done.

For instance, I want to convert 1.1 to 2, 3.01 to 4, 4.009 to 5 or any decimal numbers.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what is ceiling and floor?

Answer (score 4):

That's the ceiling function, matlab [`ceil`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html):

```
>> ceil(1.1)

ans =

     2

>> ceil(3.01)

ans =

     4

>> ceil(4.009)

ans =

     5
```

Comment: Oh I really don't know about it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @green if you read MATLAB's official documentation of [`fix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) or [`round`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html), you can see in the "See Also" section (at the bottom) that `ceil` and `floor` are mentioned too.